# Java threads deadlock example

Tags: java, concurrency

I have been trying to read *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming* by Herlihy and Shavit. In the second chapter they motivate Peterson's algorithm with two incorrect lock implementations. I was trying to understand the problem with the LockTwo class and ended with the following code which deadlocks. A sample output is given after the code where the threads don't print all the values from 1 to 100 before deadlock. For deadlock to occur in either thread, the `while(victim ==i){}` has to run forever. But if both threads are running this loop then one of them has to exit because `victim` cannot be 0 and 1 at the same time. Am I missing something cache-related?

```
class Counter
{
    private int value;
    private int maxValue;
    public Counter(int value, int maxValue)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public int getMaxValue()
    {
        return maxValue;
    }

    public void incrementValue()
    {
        value++;
    }
}

class ThreadID 
{
  private static volatile int nextID = 0;
  private static ThreadLocalID threadID = new ThreadLocalID();

  public static int get() 
  {
    return threadID.get();
  }

  public static void reset() 
  {
    nextID = 0;
  }

  private static class ThreadLocalID extends ThreadLocal<Integer> 
  {
    protected synchronized Integer initialValue() 
    {
      return nextID++;
    }
  }
}

class IncrementThread implements Runnable
{
    private static Counter c = new Counter(0,100);
    private static LockTwo lock2 = new LockTwo();
    public IncrementThread()
    {
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int j = ThreadID.get();
        String m = "Thread ID " + j;
        //System.out.println(m);                        
        while(c.getValue() < c.getMaxValue())
        {
            lock2.lock();
            c.incrementValue();
            String s = "Value in counter is " + c.getValue() + " in thread " + j;
            System.out.println(s);                        
            lock2.unlock();
        }
    }
}

interface Lock
{
    public void lock();
    public void unlock();
}


class LockTwo implements Lock
{
    private int victim;
    public LockTwo() {};
    public void lock()
    {
        int i = ThreadID.get();
        victim = i;
        System.out.println("Trying to acquire lock in thread " + i +" with victim " + victim);
        while(victim == i) {} 
        System.out.println("Lock acquired in thread " + i + " with victim " + victim);
    }

    public void unlock()
    {
        int i = ThreadID.get();
        //victim = i;
        System.out.println("Lock released in thread " + i + " with victim " + victim);
    }
}

public class SharedCounter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread thread[] = new Thread[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < thread.length; i++)
        {
            thread[i] = new Thread(new IncrementThread());
            thread[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output
`$java SharedCounter`

```
Trying to acquire lock in thread 0 with victim 1
Trying to acquire lock in thread 1 with victim 1
Lock acquired in thread 0 with victim 1
Value in counter is 1 in thread 0
Lock released in thread 0 with victim 1
Trying to acquire lock in thread 0 with victim 0
Lock acquired in thread 1 with victim 0
Value in counter is 2 in thread 1
Lock released in thread 1 with victim 0
Trying to acquire lock in thread 1 with victim 1
Lock acquired in thread 0 with victim 1
Value in counter is 3 in thread 0
Lock released in thread 0 with victim 1
Trying to acquire lock in thread 0 with victim 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that `victim` is not volatile.
Variables in java can be cached locally to the thread.

This means each thread has it's own view of victim, each with it's own id.
I.e. Thread 0 has `victim == 0` and Thread1 has `victim == 1`

Using volatile tells the jvm that the variable will be used across threads and that it should not be cached.

Comment: If the lack of the `volatile` keyword was the problem, the threads should deadlock immediately, they should never be able to increment the counter. But this does not happen. They deadlock after a few successful passes through the critical section. BTW, the `LockTwo` implementation in ArtofMP has the `volatile` keyword associated with `victim` but the errata asks that this keyword be removed. [ArtofMP errata link](http://www.elsevierdirect.com/companions/9780123705914/software/Errata.doc)

Comment: @sarva So removing the volatile keyword still causes deadlocks?

Comment: The code above (which does not have the `volatile` keyword) results in a deadlock. If I add the `volatile` keyword to `victim`, then there is a deadlock at the very end when one thread finishes executing by incrementing the counter to 100 and the other thread is waiting in `while(victim == i) {}` with no change in the value of `victim`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer builds on Jim's answer, and the comments associated with it.

> If the lack of the `volatile` keyword was the problem, the threads should deadlock immediately, they should never be able to increment the counter. -- sarva

This is incorrect, there are no way of guaranteeing when the written value will propagate to other threads.

> BTW, the `LockTwo` implementation in ArtofMP has the `volatile` keyword associated with `victim` but the errata asks that this keyword be removed. -- sarva

This is only because consistency with the other algorithms presented in the same chapter. Pragma 2.3.1 says that `victim`, `label` and so on need to be declared `volatile` in practice -- but then `victim` is declared `volatile` in Figure 2.5 anyway.

> If I add the `volatile` keyword to `victim`, then there is a deadlock at the very end when one thread finishes executing by incrementing the counter to 100 and the other thread is waiting in `while(victim == i) {}` with no change in the value of victim. -- sarva

This is the behavior you want. Consider a single-threaded program, the following lines from your program does not make sense then:

```
victim = i;
while (victim == i) {}
```

Without an additional thread, this will be an infinite loop.

We can get an essentially equivalent situation in a two-threaded program when only one of the threads tries to acquire the lock (i.e., call the `lock` method).

If both threads call the `lock` method, we get the behavior you observed where the deadlock occurs in the end:

1. The first thread calls `lock` and sets `victim` to 0 and starts to loop
2. The second thread calls `lock` and sets `victim` to 1, and starts to loop
3. The first thread sees that `victim` now equals 1 and enters the critical section
4. If the first thread never calls the `lock` method again, the second thread will be stuck in the loop forever, waiting for `victim` to become 1

So, the (in some sense) last call will not finish if both threads call the `lock` method multiple times each.